# Remove Empty Space After Removing Blogger Navbar (Simple Template)

Tags: html, css, padding, blogger

I want the navbar to be at the top of the page. (Blogger, Simple Template).
As you can see, I switched the Blogger navbar to "Off".

[image: blog picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css code to blogger, either from **Layout**  >  **template designer** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS**

or

add directly to **Template**  >  **edit HTML** > `b:skin` just before `]]>`

```
.navbar {
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
 }
 body .navbar{
    height: 0;
 }
```

Comment: which is the code to add, and where should it be added? Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: I added it to the CSS, but no change happened.

Comment: I also tried adding it to the HTML, but nothing happened. Maybe there is some padding or margin value I need to find?

Comment: Add a screenshot(s) showing where you added the code.

Comment: added the screenshot, @simr.

Comment: Screenshot added @Simr

Comment: @DaniSpringer did you remove the navbar?

Comment: No. Just the header @simr

Answer (score 0):

### CSS-only fix

You have a div with an ID of `navbar` (`<div class="navbar section" id="navbar">`) that is empty and is taking up that space.

If you remove the div or set `display: none;` on the `#navbar` div, that space will be removed. Example:

```
#navbar {
    display: none;
}
```

You will also need to change the margin of `.content-outer`, as that will create space too (the `!important` will enable this style to override any others applied to the element). Example:

```
.content-outer {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

### HTML-only fix (for `.navbar`)

(Now that the template screenshot has been posted), you can just *remove the following code from the template* as shown in the screenshot:

```
<b:section class='navbar' id='navbar' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
  <b:widget id='Navbar1' locked='true' title='Navbar' type='Navbar'>...</b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Comment: how come I can't find any similar code to that by searching my html? @nerdwood

Comment: It's definitely in the HTML. It's immediately after the opening `<body>` tag.

Comment: I can't even find this: <body>. I should note that I am in the blogger html editor.

Comment: OK, it probably won't be showing you all of the HTML structure of the website (because Blogger is set up to make things simpler to use). If you add the CSS, the `navbar` should disappear.

Comment: I see it when inspecting on Chrome, but not on the blog's html (what?)

Comment: you mean i must add custom css?

Comment: Yep, just add some custom CSS, that's the least invasive way of fixing the issue. Blogger's HTML editor isn't showing you all the code being generated, but Chrome is showing you exactly what the page is made up of.

Comment: wait does it make sense that the code you gave me to edit appears right after the opening html (doctype) tag?

Comment: If you're using Blogger, use the Template Designer to edit the CSS: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/175740?vid=1-635799532918073836-2713666066

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91800/discussion-between-nerdwood-and-dani-springer).

Comment: I've added an HTML-only fix now that you have added the screenshot of the template code - you should still be able to use the CSS-only fix though.

Comment: I removed the above-written HTML, and it did indeed remove some space, but not all. What else should I do? Btw, "why don't I just remove the code?" Simple: I had no idea.. :)

Comment: There's also space being created by `margin-top` on `.content-outer`, but you won't be able to modify the HTML to fix this one, you'll need to override the CSS. I'll update the answer. :)

Comment: Ty. Should I maybe edit this: <Variable name="content.margin" description="Content Margin Top" type="length" default="20px" min="0" max="100px" value="20px"/>

Comment: You might be able to change the variable for it, but it's pretty easy to add the CSS override via _Layout > Template Designer > Advanced > Add CSS_.

Comment: Ok, I don't see the CSS in the answer. Did you post it yet?

Comment: But anyhow I wouldn't change it's variable, rather the 20px to 0.

Comment: The CSS to use is in the answer - the `.content-outer` part. You might need to refresh the page, sometimes the answers don't update very well. Changing the variable's value from `20px` to `0` will affect margin top, right, bottom and left, not just the top margin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92204/discussion-between-dani-springer-and-nerdwood).

Comment: I didn't know updating can take time. We'll try again G-d willing!

Comment: Looks like the space is gone now off the website, so you can mark this one as solved now to help out other people.  :)

Comment: I didn't try the code yet I think. I'll try, check, and mark accordingly! Ty

Answer (score 0):

Fix by html (add `style="height:0"`)

```
<div class="navbar section" id="navbar" **style="height:0"**>
```

Fix by css:

```
body .navbar {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: i cant find that div in the blog's html.

Comment: you won't find that *div* from blogger backend, its dynamically generated by blogger.

Comment: So I should just add the HTML you provided anywhere on the code?